# SQL IN Operator equivalent in Elastic Search with Nest Client

Tags: .net, elasticsearch, lambda, nest

I am facing problem in filtering the search trying to match list of values.

Here is my Code

```
List<string> DepartmentIds = new List<string>(){"d1","d2","d3","d4"};

term = "*" + "akshay" + "*"

var searchResults = client.Search<Employee>(c => c
                          .Index(index)
                          .Type(type)
                          .Query(+q.Term(f => f.DeptId.ToLower(), DepartmentIds))   // Facing Issue in Matching list of Department IDs
                            && ((q.Wildcard(wc => wc.Field(f => f.FirstName).Value(term)))                        
                                 || (q.Wildcard(wc => wc.Field(f => f.LastName).Value(term)))                       
                                 ));
```

Say there are 10 departments and i want to fetch results from department D1,D2,D3 and D4. I should basically see if the department ids in the indexed document matches any of the 4 departments.

As the number of department ids and their values will be dynamic. I want to basically find the equivalent of sql in operator in NEST Client so that i can  filter my search appropriately.

Comment: What if you use `Terms` instead of `Term`?

Comment: Hi Val. Could you provide  an example of using terms.

Comment: Try `q.Terms(f => f.DeptId.ToLower(), DepartmentIds)` instead of `q.Term(f => f.DeptId.ToLower(), DepartmentIds)`

Comment: There is no such syntax for Terms. Terms Support only one syntax
public QueryContainer Terms(Func<TermsQueryDescriptor<T>, ITermsQuery> selector);

Comment: What version of NEST are you using and what version of Elasticsearch are you running against?

Comment: Hi Rus. I am using the version 2.0.5 https://www.nuget.org/packages/NEST/2.0.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a **[`Terms` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/terms-list-query-usage.html)** for this

```
List<string> departmentIds = new List<string>() { "d1", "d2", "d3", "d4" };

var term = "*" + "akshay" + "*";
var index = "index";
var type = "type";

var searchResults = client.Search<Employee>(c => c
    .Index(index)
    .Type(type)
    .Query(q => 
        +q.Terms(t => t
            .Field(f => f.DeptId)
            .Terms<string>(departmentIds)
        ) && (
            q.Wildcard(wc => wc.Field(f => f.FirstName).Value(term)) || 
            q.Wildcard(wc => wc.Field(f => f.LastName).Value(term))
        )
    )
);
```

will produce the following query

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "filter": [
              {
                "terms": {
                  "deptId": [
                    "d1",
                    "d2",
                    "d3",
                    "d4"
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "wildcard": {
                  "firstName": {
                    "value": "*akshay*"
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "wildcard": {
                  "lastName": {
                    "value": "*akshay*"
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Bear in mind that [wildcard queries can be slow and **it is recommended not to start them with the `*` wilcard**](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html).

You might want to look at **[completion suggesters](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/search-suggesters-completion.html)** for what you are doing

Comment: Thank You Rus, Also thank you for the wildcard recommendation. How do you predict the output of the query. I am using Visual Studio. Is there a way where I can get the output query??

Comment: Take a look at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/connecting.html#complex-logging for logging out requests and responses. I would recommend using this in development